Executing NOT EXISTS clause based on boolean function parameter
Here is my code as part of a WHERE clause:
AND (
            NOT ignoredwp 
            OR NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM filtering f 
                WHERE f."IMEI" = cp.imei 
                  AND f.date = cp."generatedAt"::date
            )
        )

ignoredwp is a boolean parameter. Am I right in saying that if ignoredwp is true, only then the rest of the "OR NOT EXISTS" part will be evaluated? Basically, I want to only execute the NOT EXISTS check when the parameter is true.

You can't guarantee in which order they will be evaluated; but you can add and additional condition around NOT EXISTS , i.e. ` AND (NOT ignoredwp OR (ignoredwp AND EXISTS (...)))

I tried using  IF ignoredwp THEN
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM filtering f
WHERE f."IMEI" = cp.imei
AND f.date = cp."generatedAt"::date
)
END IF . but it throws an error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"

Support for an IF statement depends on in the rdbms you are using. Please tag what database you are using and show your entire WHERE clause

based on your original comment, this works: AND (
NOT ignoredwp
OR (ignoredwp AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM filtering f
WHERE f."IMEI" = cp.imei
AND f.date = cp."generatedAt"::date
))
)

Trust the optimizer.

You can't guarantee in which order they will be evaluated; but you can add and additional condition around NOT EXISTS , i.e. ` AND (NOT ignoredwp OR (ignoredwp AND EXISTS (...))):
...
AND (
      NOT ignoredwp 
      OR ( ignoredwp
           AND NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT 1 
                       FROM filtering f 
                       WHERE f."IMEI" = cp.imei 
                       AND f.date = cp."generatedAt"::date
                     )
         )
     )

